# C++ vector with pointer

Tags: c++

I am stuck on a homework assignment. I have to read text from a file, allocate each word to memory, then user a pointer to send it to a `vector<string*>`. My program keeps overwriting the vector with the new word from the file instead of just adding it. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void WordFunctions(string *pstr, vector<string*> &words)
{
    words.push_back(pstr);
}
int main(){
    ifstream file;
    vector<string*> a;
    string word;
    int w =0;
    file.open("word.txt");
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        w++;
        file >> word;

        WordFunctions(&word, a);
    }
    file.close();

     for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<(*a[i])<<" ";
        delete a[i];
    }

     system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Geez... your assignment actually forces you to use a vector of pointers and doesn't explain why this is a horrible idea?  Just so you know, you now have the burden of deallocating every element in your vector manually, negating a huge benefit that vector gives you.  *sometimes* you need to store pointers in  vector (not often!) and in that case you would use a smart pointer, i.e., `unique_ptr` or something similar.  Make sure to tell your teacher this next time you see him/her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use a `vector<string>` or allocate the new string on the heap:

```
void WordFunctions(string *pstr, vector<string*> &words)
{
    words.push_back(new string(*pstr));
}
```

Comment: Surely it's better to pass the value by const ref rather than pointer ? then no nasty dereferencing etc...

Comment: @Caribou Yes, it is. But I wanted to go with minimal changes. Otherwise you must change the calling site as well.

Comment: true - was just cringing here ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same element into vector which is the address of word. I massage a bit on your code

```
// pass reference to eliminate copy
void WordFunctions(string &str, vector<string> &words)
{
    words.push_back(str);
}
int main(){
    ifstream file;
    vector<string> a;  // you want to store string not the address of the string
    string word;
    int w =0;
    file.open("words.txt");
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        w++;
        word.clear();   // clear the content before store something into it
        file >> word;
        WordFunctions(word, a);
    }
    file.close();

     for (size_t i=0;i<a.size();i++){  // use size instead of hard code magic number
        cout<<(a.at(i))<<" ";  // use at function instead of []
    }

     system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your `word` string has always the same address in memory, so in the loop you are changing the value of the string, but then you call `WordFunctions` passing to him always the same address.

If it's a constraint to use `vector<string*>` instead of `vector<string>`, you will likely need to allocate memory for new strings in the loop, copy there your word and then pass the new reference to `WordFunctions`

```
char *wordPtr

while (!file.eof())
{
    w++;
    file >> word;

    wordPtr = (char *)malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(wordPtr, *word);

    WordFunctions(wordPtr, a);
}
```

Comment: Hey, this guy is trying to use c++. Why do you propose to use `malloc`?

Comment: You are right! It was so similar to the classical homeworks I did in C that I solved it that way! Saw now the correct solution and upvoted